# read bytes from file in custom (template) array

Tags: c#, .net, readfile

I have a binary file. One piece of data can be 8,16,32,64 bit signed and unsigned int. I'm trying to write the template function and here is what I've done until now:

```
    public T[] GetLayerBytes<T>(int LayerNum)
    {
        int typeSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

        int layerPixelCount = typeSize * bitmapWidth * bitmapHeigth;

        string recFileName = "my.rec";

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(recFileName))
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            fs.Seek(layerPixelCount * LayerNum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            T[] b = new T[layerPixelCount];

            //fs.Read(b, 0, layerPixelCount); this doesn't work
            //br.Read(b, 0, layerPixelCount); this doesn't work too
            return b;
        }
    }
```

In C++ I would use [CFile::Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ctka0kks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this.

Is there any way to read bytes/int16/uint16 etc. similar to what I've tried without switch/cases for different `T` types?

Thanks in advance for all possible ellegant solutions.

Comment: This might help you [BinaryFormatter.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz.aspx) - look at the example at the bottom..

Comment: @Blachshma thanks, I think it could be my solution. Do you know how I can deserialize only a specific range and not the whole sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'd recommend using the [BinaryFormatter.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz.aspx) method.

The BinaryFormatter has a **[Binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder.aspx)** property which you can use for choosing the type of the object you want.

In addition, I think you'll want to use the **[SurrogateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector.aspx)** in order to *transform* the serialized data however you want...

Comment: thanks, but what about reading only a known range of bytes? My files are bigger than 40 GB so I can't read them to the end

Comment: BinaryFormatter receives a stream, you can play with the size, position of the stream however you like. For example, with [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)  you can map a part of a large file, and access just that part of the file using a Stream.